How do I make my table span the entire textwidth without affecting the height
For the purpose of my dissertation, I have been trying to create a table of summary statistics for my dataset. The code for my table is as follows
\begin{table}[h!] 
    \centering 
    \caption{\bfseries Summary Statistics}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lrrrrrrr}
    \hline
    \hline
    Variable & N & Mean & Std. Dev. & Min & Pctl. 25 & Pctl. 75 & Max \\ 
    \hline
    AGE & 5908926 & 55 & 17 & 7 & 42 & 69 & 99 \\ 
    EDUCA & 5881970 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 1 & 8330 & 0\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 2 & 147572 & 3\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 3 & 301039 & 5\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 4 & 1638625 & 28\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 5 & 1610594 & 27\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 6 & 2175810 & 37\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    EMPLOY & 5843383 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 1 & 2418997 & 41\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 2 & 501527 & 9\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 3 & 144315 & 2\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 4 & 139411 & 2\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 5 & 334316 & 6\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 6 & 145740 & 2\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 7 & 1741797 & 30\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 8 & 417280 & 7\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    EXERANY2 & 5749588 & 0.74 & 0.44 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
    INCOME2 & 4899017 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 1 & 244321 & 5\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 2 & 260714 & 5\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 3 & 351815 & 7\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 4 & 438090 & 9\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 5 & 552056 & 11\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 6 & 700566 & 14\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 7 & 785529 & 16\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 8 & 1383202 & 28\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 9 & 97972 & 2\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 10 & 42322 & 1\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 11 & 42430 & 1\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    MEDCOST & 5891545 & 0.11 & 0.31 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
    ORACE2 & 3989021 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 1 & 3363496 & 84\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 2 & 352440 & 9\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 3 & 87848 & 2\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 4 & 105369 & 3\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 5 & 56550 & 1\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    ... 6 & 23318 & 1\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    POORHLTH & 3032576 & 5.3 & 9.3 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 30 \\ 
    MALE & 5908928 & 0.43 & 0.51 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 9 \\ 
    TREAT & 4121658 & 0.71 & 0.46 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
    POST & 5908928 & 0.67 & 0.47 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\ 
    \hline
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

I have also attached a screenshot so you can see exactly what is going on.

I was hoping to make the table and its contents properly span the entire width without it affecting the table height and the font size. How do you recommend I go about it?

You must use an X column for tabularx to work its magic of spreading a table over the specified width properly (\textwidth in your case). The assumption is that you need \begin{tabular}{ l *{7}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X } }, but some additional formatting would help with the use of siunitx-style column formatting.

As @Werner has already noted in a comment, it's a first-order error to employ a tabularx environment without at least one type-X column.
That said, for the table at hand, it would be better to switch from a tabularx to a tabular* setup, for two reasons. First, automatic line-breaking within cells isn't needed anywhere. Second, the natural column widths vary noticeably across the 7 data columns, casting doubt on the usefulness of making them have equal widths. (Equal widths would result from employing a tabularx environment and specifying *{7}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X.)
In addition, I would like to suggest that you employ the booktabs package and some of its user macros -- specifically: \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule -- instead of \hline and \hline\hline, in order to give the table more open "look".
Here's a screenshot of the resulting table.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex} \ifpdftex \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \fi
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip,textfont=bf}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make LaTeX determine optimal amount of intercolumn whitespace
\caption{Summary Statistics}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{7}{r} }
    \toprule
    Variable & N & Mean & St.Dev. & Min & Pctl.\ 25 & Pctl.\ 75 & Max \\ 
    \midrule
    AGE      & 5908926 & 55 & 17 & 7 & 42 & 69 & 99 \\ 
    EDUCA    & 5881970 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  1 &    8330 &  0\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  2 &  147572 &  3\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  3 &  301039 &  5\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  4 & 1638625 & 28\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  5 & 1610594 & 27\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  6 & 2175810 & 37\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    EMPLOY   & 5843383 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  1 & 2418997 & 41\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  2 &  501527 &  9\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  3 &  144315 &  2\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  4 &  139411 &  2\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  5 &  334316 &  6\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  6 &  145740 &  2\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  7 & 1741797 & 30\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  8 &  417280 &  7\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    EXERANY2 & 5749588 & 0.74 & 0.44 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
    INCOME2  & 4899017 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  1 &  244321 &  5\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  2 &  260714 &  5\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  3 &  351815 &  7\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  4 &  438090 &  9\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  5 &  552056 & 11\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  6 &  700566 & 14\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  7 &  785529 & 16\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  8 & 1383202 & 28\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  9 &   97972 &  2\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots 10 &   42322 &  1\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots 11 &   42430 &  1\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    MEDCOST  & 5891545 & 0.11 & 0.31 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
    ORACE2   & 3989021 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  1 & 3363496 & 84\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  2 &  352440 &  9\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  3 &   87848 &  2\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  4 &  105369 &  3\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  5 &   56550 &  1\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \dots  6 &   23318 &  1\% &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    POORHLTH & 3032576 & 5.3  & 9.3  & 0 & 0 & 5 & 30 \\ 
    MALE     & 5908928 & 0.43 & 0.51 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 9 \\ 
    TREAT    & 4121658 & 0.71 & 0.46 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
    POST     & 5908928 & 0.67 & 0.47 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Thank you very much for this. I've used Latex before but never in such a detailed capacity so this helps out!
